# Giving a label highlight effect - Java SWT

Tags: java, swt

Is there a way in Java to give a label a highlight effect?
For example, say I have a label with a picture set to it, and I want to highlight it whenever the mouse cursor enters it.
I tried to look around in google and the only tip I could find is to use `label.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));`
but this obviously will not highlight the label, let alone a label with a picture on it.
because first of all, it is **too** yellow, and second, it will appear as if the color is behind the picture (well, because it is setBackground() of course).
I'm looking for a much brighter yellow color that will also be transparent, so the image will be seen.
Hope my intentions are clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `Listener` to `SWT.MouseEnter` and `SWT.MouseExit` and keep track of whether the mouse is hovering over the `Label` and then repaint it with a custom `Listener` for `SWT.Paint`:

```
private static boolean hovering = false;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    final Image image = display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_ERROR);

    Listener mouseHover = new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            hovering = e.type == SWT.MouseEnter;
            label.redraw();
        }
    };

    label.addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, mouseHover);
    label.addListener(SWT.MouseExit, mouseHover);
    label.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            int x = label.getBounds().width / 2 - image.getBounds().width / 2;
            int y = label.getBounds().height / 2 - image.getBounds().height / 2;
            e.gc.drawImage(image, x, y);

            if(hovering)
            {
                e.gc.setAlpha(50);
                e.gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));
                e.gc.fillRectangle(label.getBounds());
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(100, 100);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]
[image]